# flutter:: Is there a flutter package that allows me to visually see my volume?

Tags: flutter, google-speech-api

I am using google speech to text api and google speech flutter package.
When a voice is input, I want to express the volume of the voice in the form of a bar.
I want to make a widget where the blue bar moves to the right when the voice is louder,
and the blue bar moves to the left when the voice is lowered.

Can you tell me if there is a flutter package that can make these bars?

This is example.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [Noise Meter](https://pub.dev/packages/noise_meter/example) package.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I have one more question. It seems that noise_meter only tells db information and does not provide bar form. What package should I use to express the decibel data in bar form? The bar should keep moving in decibels while voice is being recognized.